# If Else, Then Divide by columns in that search

Tags: excel

How can you go about creating calculations if your query is active? I have an excel file where I run a query

For the Average Goals I have this query

=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A3,M2:M19,0)),"False", ((R2+S2)/N2))

How can I get it to display the same query but when it finds the match it automatically does the query for me?

This is the file which I'm using.
http://i.gyazo.com/4f5674c766dd915d5488a83ff5b70e46.png

Comment: Can you clarify? I don't quite get what you mean by "do the query for me".  Where does your formula go in your linked worksheet?

Comment: I think you might be confusing `formula` with `query` ?

Comment: I have this formula

=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A3,M2:M19,0)),"False", ((R2+S2)/N2))

The basic logic behind it is it tries to search for a match in a list I’ve created. Once it does this it will either say if it is in the list, or not. If it is in the list then it will do the query of  ((R2+S2)/N2)). How can I get it to do this query so that when it finds the match it was find the cell that this match was found in?

Comment: @user3723217 Ohhhhhh Okay.  Hold on I can fix it

Answer (score 0):

**Use INDEX and MATCH**

Use your existing `MATCH` i.e. `MATCH(A3,M2:M19,0)` inside an `INDEX` formula:

```
=IFERROR((INDEX(R:R,MATCH($A3,M:M,0)) + INDEX(S:S,MATCH($A3,M:M,0)))/(INDEX(N:N,MATCH($A3,M:M,0))),"False")
```

(Note: I changed the reference from `M2:M19` to the `M:M` (the entire column).  You can change this back if you are not planning on adding data)